# Finding a number n, such that order of 2 modulo n is a prime number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can you find a solution to the equation $Ord{ _{ n } }{ 2 }=p$ such as. $Ord{ _{ n } }{ 2 }=11$ without having to calculate $Ord{ _{ n } }{ 2 }$ for all the numbers (n) up to $2^{11} - 1$? For example, the above equation is solved by $n = 23$ or $n = 89$, is there anyway we can decrease the number of ns that we look into.

I know that $Ord{ _{ n } }{ 2 }$ divides $\varphi (n)$ but I don't see how this could help me in this situation.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\text{Ord}_n 2$?  Write down what $\text{Ord}_n 2 = 11$ and see what it tells you about $n$ (hint: it says a very great deal about $n$).  P.S. Did you notice that $23 \cdot 89 = 2^{11} - 1$?

Comment: $Ord_{ n }{ 2 }$ is the least k such that ${ 2 }^{ k }\quad \equiv \quad 1\quad mod\quad (n)$. So in my case of 11, I would want it to be ${ 2 }^{ 11 }\quad \equiv \quad 1\quad mod\quad (n)$ Which means that n could be 1 more than a multiple of $2^{11} - 1$ ?? But wouldn't this mean that I would have to factorize $2^{11} - 1$ just to reach n which could be an even more difficult thing to do for large p?

Comment: You're a little confused, but you have the right idea.  $n$ must divide $2^{11} - 1$, so $n$ is a factor of $2^{11} - 1$, not a multiple.  Notice that factoring $2^{11}-1$ cannot possibly be as hard as computing ord for every number up to $2^{11}-1$, since factoring can be done in a lot of ways, the simplest of which is dividing by every number up to $\sqrt{2^{11}-1} \approx 45$.